# HTTP error 400 in R, error handling, How to retry instead of forcing to stop?

Tags: r, api, curl, error-handling, try-catch

I am calling API to download files using `curl` package in R. Due to unknown reason, sometimes the connection breaks with error code: `Error in curl_download(url = i, handle = h, df) : HTTP error 400.`

Because I need to download about 100,000 files at a time and it's very slow, I wish R could retry once this error occurs instead of throwing me an error and stopping the script. Any thoughts?

my code is (simple version):

```
for (url in allUrl) {
  df <- tempfile()
    tryCatch(
      curl_download(url = url,
                    handle = h,
                    df)
    )
}
```

Comment: see `httr::RETRY`

Comment: @alistaire Can I use it to download files?

Comment: If you read `?RETRY`, it supports all of `httr`'s standard "verbs", including `GET` and `POST`, so *yes*, you can use it to download files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [Hadley package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.3.1/topics/RETRY) designed exactly for this

```
require(httr)
maxTimes <- 10
testFilename <- "testfile.txt"

for (url in allUrl) {
  RETRY(verb = "GET", url = url, times = maxTimes,
    quiet = FALSE, terminate_on = NULL)
}
```

Specifially for file downloads with authentication, you can replace the RETRY command with:

```
GET(url, write_disk(path=testFilename, overwrite=TRUE), authenticate("user", "passwd"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the `GET` function, but it said `Error in write_disk(filename = df, overwrite = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (filename = df)`

Comment: BTW, if I stick with `RETRY`, how can I put `df` in it? And I'm not familiar with handle in `httr`, do you mind give me some instructions on how to set username and password with `httr`? Thank you!

Comment: @Arthur, I've fixed the code for GET. The package has been updated to "path" being the parameter.

Comment: I've added the username/password to the solution. For future reference, it would be better to include that component of your code in the original question.

Comment: Thank you very much, so `GET` alone has the ability to retry?

Comment: @Arthur, actually, I think you should instead supply those arguments to RETRY to be safe. It's been a while. i.e. use RETRY(verb = "GET", url = url, times = maxTimes, quiet = FALSE, terminate_on = NULL, write_disk(path=testFilename, overwrite=TRUE), authenticate("user", "passwd"))