# What are the functions to download a URL list in R?

Tags: r, list, url, download

I have a URL list in R and want to download it.

However, I do not like to use **download.file()** as this function gives me error when my list is big (more than 500 links):

```
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
```

Here is the download list:

```
list_1 <- c("https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODV6_Cmp_A/MOLT/MOD11B3.006/2004.12.01/MOD11B3.A2004336.h18v08.006.2015240192212.hdf",
        "https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODV6_Cmp_A/MOLT/MOD11B3.006/2004.12.01/MOD11B3.A2004336.h19v07.006.2015240192220.hdf",
        "https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODV6_Cmp_A/MOLT/MOD11B3.006/2004.12.01/MOD11B3.A2004336.h19v08.006.2015240192212.hdf",
        "https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODV6_Cmp_A/MOLT/MOD11B3.006/2004.12.01/MOD11B3.A2004336.h18v07.006.2015240192213.hdf")

list_1
```

Any idea to download this list using a better function in R?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Before posting, I went through the existed questions suggested by the website. However, I did not find the similar one. Could you please share the link for the one you mentioned?

Comment: If you are getting an operation time out, it's likely that you are probably just overloading the server. Asking for a large number of files at one time is not a nice thing to do to a server (especially if those files are large). Use a loop and add some wait time between requests.

Comment: Thanks. Despite using **options(timeout=600)**, this function still give me the error sometime.

Comment: MrFlick, please remove this from the page: This question already has an answer here. Because as I said that is not the case

Comment: If you want to automatically retry on failure, then try an option like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067906/http-error-400-in-r-error-handling-how-to-retry-instead-of-forcing-to-stop

Comment: You've tried all 6 answers on all 4 questions and none of them worked? If that's the case, you should add whatever information would set your question apart from the previous ones.

Comment: Good. Let me check all those methods. If they worked, I will delete my question here.

Comment: @lilster , I tried to employ your code in order to solve my question here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067906/http-error-400-in-r-error-handling-how-to-retry-instead-of-forcing-to-stop/56157389#56157389
But I could not. Could you please help me with that?

Appreciate.